# uWSGI with Django gives Broken pipe

Tags: python, django, pipe, uwsgi

I am using uWsgi + Django to write web services for an android application to submit survey data which is normally not very large set of data but, the application sends multiple calls to the server. If the surveyor has done 50 surveys, he'll tap one button on his mobile and all the surveys will be sent to the server one by one in one go. Sometimes I get the BROKEN PIPE error. Data is saved on the server but response is not sent back to the mobile due to which those surveys are not removed from the mobile and next time all those surveys are again sent to the surveys along with the new ones and it is causing a lot of duplication.

PLEASE HELP....

Answer (score 0):

check the timeout of your frontend server, generally if there is no activity, the connection is closed. For example nginx has 60 seconds timeout

Comment: There is no way that the nginx timesout cuz the request does not take more than 30-40 seconds but still i get broken pipe error.